# How to make 2D array with numbers winding clockwise in C++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I need to create a 2D array winded clockwise in C++ like below:

```
789
612
543
```

The problem is i didn't find a good algorithm for it.

I try to change x and y and change the indexes every time but how should I change `x` and `y`?

For example I tried:

```
int num[1001][1001];
int n = 1;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

for (int i = 500; i < 1001 && i >= 0; i++)
{
    for (int j = 500; j < 1001 && j >= 0; i++)
    {
        num[i + x][j + y] = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `i >= 0`condition? `i` is initialized to `500`, and only incremented, can never be `<500`, unless overflow occurs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but this code will eventually try to dereference `num[1001][500]` and invoke undefined behavior.  Are you trying to initialize every index in your array with 1, and did you mean to increment `j` in the second loop?

Comment: Your example array is either 3x3 or 3x1 (unclear) but your code has a 1001x1001 array, of which you only try to access a quarter. Please clarify your intention.

Comment: Also, where should 10 go: east of 9 or two columns east of 1? More general, should the spiral be contiguous or always start at the middle row?

Comment: @RakibulHasan worse questions have been left unchallenged. This one could be anwsered perfectly well.

Comment: Why is this on hold as "unclear"? It makes perfect sense to me and was answered perfectly with a solution by luane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `n = 2k + 1` be the dimension of the array.

Let `s` be the number of the spiral, with `s=0` being the center (1).

Then you need 5 loops for each spiral:

```
iterating from [k+1,k+1+s] to [k+1+s,k+1+s]
from [k+1+s,k+1+s-1] to [k+1+s,k+1-s]
from [k+1+s-1,k+1-s] to [k+1-s,k+1-s]
from [k+1-s,k+1-s+1] to [k+1-s,k+1+s]
from [k+1-s+1,k+1+s] to [k,k+1+s]
```

I may have made a mistake here, but the general idea should help.

**Later**

I've added the complete program, but here the spiral continues as opposed to the index bounds given above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
static const int k = 3;
static const int n = 2*k+1;
int a[n][n];
void set(int r, int c, int v){
  a[r-1][c-1] = v;
}
void dump(){
  for( int r = 0; r < n; r++ ){
    for( int c = 0; c < n; c++ ){
      std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << a[r][c];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
int main(){
  int v = 2;
  set( k+1,k+1,1);
  for( int s = 1; s <= k; s++ ){
    for( int r = k+1-s+1; r <= k+1+s; r++ ) set( r, k+1+s, v++ );
    for( int c = k+1+s-1; c >= k+1-s; c-- ) set( k+1+s, c, v++ );
    for( int r = k+1+s-1; r >= k+1-s; r-- ) set( r, k+1-s, v++ );
    for( int c = k+1-s+1; c <= k+1+s; c++ ) set( k+1-s, c, v++ );
  }
  dump();
  //...
```

}

Running this with k set to 2 produces:

```
21 22 23 24 25
20  7  8  9 10
19  6  1  2 11
18  5  4  3 12
17 16 15 14 13
```

Comment: hi!! thanks a lot! but there is a problem, may you put k = 2 and print the array? thanks a lot

Comment: no! there was a little mistake! thanks a lot! it works perfectly :))

Comment: It doesnt work with n = 2, is that a problem?

Comment: @Ben Looking at the (single) example, I ruled out that n could be even.

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple example, you have the following start of an array:

```
   7  8  9 10
   6  1  2 11
   5  4  3 12
17 16 15 14 13
```

If you think about it in moves a patter emerges:

```
1 right
1 down
2 left
2 up
3 right
3 down
4 left
...
```

And what constitues a move?

```
right = +0 row +1 col
left = +0 row -1 col
up = -1 row +0 col
down = +1 row +0 col
```

So now all you need is to follow this simple algorithm until you reach an exit condition.

```
int size = 4 //or 5?
bool notReachedTheEnd = true;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid(std::vector<int>(0, size), size);
int row = (size-1)/2;
int col = row;
int counter = 1;
int movenumber = 1;
int movedamount = 0;
enum states = {LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};
states state = RIGHT;

while (notReachedTheEnd)
{
    grid[row][col] = counter++;  //Assign the current grid cell
        //Handle moves
        switch state
        {
            case LEFT:
                col--;
                movedamount++;
                if (movedamount == movednumber)
                {
                    movedamount = 0;
                    case = UP;
                }
            case RIGHT:
                row++;
                movedamount++;
                if (movedamount == movednumber)
                {
                    movedamount = 0;
                    case = DOWN;
                }
            case UP:
                row--;
                movedamount++;
                if (movedamount == movednumber)
                {
                    movedamount = 0;
                    movecount++;
                    case = RIGHT;
                }
            case DOWN:
                row++;
                movedamount++;
                if (movedamount == movednumber)
                {
                    movedamount = 0;
                    movecount++;
                    case = LEFT;
                }
          }
          //Now check exit condition
          if (row >= size || col >= size)
          {
                 break;
          }
    }
```

This is un-compiled unchecked code, but it is a good way of explaining a way to solve this problem.

Hope this helps.